# Javascript custom element's oninput function issue

Tags: javascript

Say, I need to call a function in a custom element, such that when a slider moves in that element the text gets updated(only for that element). The `main.js` file,

```
class OninputClassDemo extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();

        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});

        this.parent = document.createElement('div');

        this.slider = document.createElement('input');
        this.slider.setAttribute('type','range');
        this.slider.setAttribute('min','0');
        this.slider.setAttribute('max','99');
        this.slider.setAttribute('value','0')

        this.text = document.createElement('input');
        this.text.setAttribute('type','text');
        this.text.setAttribute('value','');

        this.parent.appendChild(this.slider);
        this.parent.appendChild(this.text);
        shadow.appendChild(this.parent);        

        this.slider.setAttribute('oninput','OninputClassDemo.changeValue()');

    }

    changeValue = function(){
        this.text.setAttribute('value',this.slider.getAttribute('value'));
    }
}

window.customElements.define('demo-element',OninputClassDemo);
```

On the template side,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <demo-element></demo-element>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I am getting is,

```
OninputClassDemo.changeValue is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput
```

I do not know how to reference the method for that particular object in `this.slider.setAttribute('oninput','WhatShouldIPutHere')`,so that the text box for only that object gets changed.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @D.Pardal I guess you wanted the full code on the template side, I added it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be binding event listeners with addEventListener. You should be binding to the method with this, not the class name. Set the value property, do not set an attribute.

```js
class OninputClassDemo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    this.parent = document.createElement('div');

    this.slider = document.createElement('input');
    this.slider.setAttribute('type', 'range');
    this.slider.setAttribute('min', '0');
    this.slider.setAttribute('max', '99');
    this.slider.setAttribute('value', '0')

    this.text = document.createElement('input');
    this.text.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    this.text.setAttribute('value', '');

    this.parent.appendChild(this.slider);
    this.parent.appendChild(this.text);
    shadow.appendChild(this.parent);

    this.slider.addEventListener('input', (event) => this.changeValue());

  }

  changeValue() {
    this.text.value = this.slider.value;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('demo-element', OninputClassDemo);
```

```html
<demo-element></demo-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
changeValue() {
    this.text.setAttribute('value',this.slider.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

instead of

```
changeValue = function(){
    this.text.setAttribute('value',this.slider.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

Comment: getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: OninputClassDemo.changeValue is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput` when I move the slider.